# Receipt Validation for Auto-renewable Subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewable

I was confused by this line in Apple's documentation:

> For non-consumable products and auto-renewable subscriptions in iOS 7
>   and later, use the app receipt as your persistent record.

When it says "receipt" here, is it referring to the data returned from verification? Or does it mean I should read values directly from the thing stored at appStoreURL (which I'm having a very difficult time figuring out how to do).

My planned approach was to store the important values that return from receipt verification in UserDefaults and periodically verifying the receipt to make sure nothing changed. Is that the correct approach?